# Use one Validation summary Control for multiple validation groups

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I would like to use a single Validation summary control to handle more than one Validation groups. Is there a way to accomplish that on the server side?

I tried to specify the validation groups in the Validation Summary control ,<asp:ValidationSummary id="vs1" ValidationGroup="VG1,VG2" run at="Server"/>, but no error messages are diaplaying.